# border-radius using a slash ("/") between two values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

By javascript or jquery method, when I try to modify css `border-radius` with 2 values using a slash between the result is without the slash.

Example :

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").style.borderRadius ="20% / 15%";
```

or :

```
$( "#mydiv" ).css({'border-radius':'20% / 15%'})
```

the result is : `border-radius: 20% 15%;` (without slash between values)

But I need this slash "/" to have different angle to define corners

Any solutions ?

**Thanks for all answeres.**

My problem is not the effect in live, yes it's work, but the writed result in the page (for saving page) because the css writed inside the bloc div is wrong : like "`<div id="mydiv" style="border-radius: 20% 15%;">` 
then when the file is readed again, the result is not like with `border-radius: 20% / 15%;`.

Comment: How about `'20% \/ 15%'`?

Comment: this method ('20% \/ 15%') dont work

Answer (score 2):

Your code works as expected in Chrome at least.
But Chrome DevTools shows this property wrong.

```js
$('#s').on('click', function() {
    $('#mydiv').css({'border-radius': '20% / 5%'});
});
$('#d').on('click', function() {
    alert($('#mydiv').css('border-radius'));
});
```

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #000;
}
button {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<button id="d">get border-radius</button>
<button id="s">set border-radius</button>
```

Comment: This is the one and only correct solution. [I made another fiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/929wn8cm/). No matter if you use a slash or not, dev tools will return a value without slash - even though it renders correctly. Note that when toggling the property off and back on again, it will render as the value without slash!

Comment: yes in live it's working, but i need to save the result, and the result css writed is wrong,

Comment: @ChristopheMartin how you trying to save it? `$('#mydiv').css('border-radius')` returns correct result - save it

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to antislash it ?

```
20% **\**/ 15%'})
```

(remove **)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to specify all the values and not use the shorthand, for example ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius)):

```css
border-radius: 4px 3px 6px / 2px 4px;

/* is equivalent to: */

border-top-left-radius:     4px 2px;
border-top-right-radius:    3px 4px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 6px 2px;
border-bottom-left-radius:  3px 4px;
```

Expanding on that, you can do this:

```js
$( "#mydiv" ).css({
  'border-top-left-radius':     '20% 5%',
  'border-top-right-radius':    '20% 5%',
  'border-bottom-right-radius': '20% 5%',
  'border-bottom-left-radius':  '20% 5%',
})

// OR

var mydivstyle = document.getElementById("mydiv").style;
mydivstyle.borderTopLeftRadius = '20% 5%';
mydivstyle.borderTopRightRadius = '20% 5%';
mydivstyle.borderBottomLeftRadius = '20% 5%';
mydivstyle.borderBottomRightRadius = '20% 5%';
```

## Working example:

#### Updated to display correct css property (requested by OP)

```js
$("#mydiv").css({
  'border-top-left-radius':     '20% 15%',
  'border-top-right-radius':    '20% 15%',
  'border-bottom-right-radius': '20% 15%',
  'border-bottom-left-radius':  '20% 15%',
});

$("#output").text(
  $("#mydiv").css('border-radius')
);
```

```css
#mydiv { height: 40px; width: 100%; background: #00f; }
#output { font-family: monospace; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<h2>Result: (<code>$("#mydiv").css('border-radius')</code>)</h2>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Details from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius)

### Update

Chrome dev tools appears to display this property inconsistently. Here are some screens:

With `style=border-radius: 10% 5%;`:

[image: no slash]

With `style=border-radius: 10% / 5%;`:

[image: with slash]

After jQuery snippet is run (reads `10% 5%` but the corner properties expand as `10% / 5%`):

[image: javascript property change]

Comment: Thanks, it could be nice, but jquery seems to make a simplification when the values are similar for each corner, the result si only border-radius: 20% 15%;

Comment: I've tested and it seems to be working correctly, although the dev tools output is inconsistent (as mentioned in another answer). I'll be updating my answer...

Comment: @ChristopheMartin take a look at this update and see if you experience the same behavior. May be a chrome bug.

Comment: yes in live it's working, but i need to save the result in file, and the result css writed by jquery or javascript is wrong, when the values are same for each corner, it make a simplification in the file.

Comment: @ChristopheMartin If you need to save the correct details, you should update your question to reflect that. We've been trying to help you solve a _different_ problem.

Comment: @ChristopheMartin I've updated to show that you _can_ access the correct value via jQuery, regardless of the incorrect display in chrome dev tools. See the snippet.

Comment: sure it's working in screen, but the result writed by javascrip/jquery method is wrong : style="border-radius: 20% 15%;" then, it's impossible to save the html page result.